# Arduino: Write on console only and not hardware

Tags: arduino

How do I write a debug var on console but not on the serial hardware?

I tried `Console.write`; I tried `Serial.flush()`.

The problem is when I print the return value (rep) for debugging it is also sent to my hardware on RX/TX and creating errors.

```
int start_of_text = 0x02;
int end_of_text = 0x03;
String cmd = "cmdtosend";
String rep = "returnvalue";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  cmd = "TV,100";
  writeCOM(cmd);
}

void writeCOM (String cmdtosend) {
  cmd = "\02\02" + cmdtosend + "\03";
  Serial.print(cmd);
  delay(200);
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      rep = Serial.readString();
  }
  cmd = " ";
  rep = " ";
  delay(800);
}
```

Comment: You should use different serial port for debugging. In case if there is only 1 serial port, `softwareserial` library will be really helpful.

Comment: I tried SoftwareSerial on other pins last project, it was not working good, com was noisy.

Comment: Im gonna use a text file for debugging I think.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong it is impossible, because these code is running on arduino, not on your computer. If you want see something from uC you must send it by serial.